# ¿Cómo hacer eventos js sobre un formulario traido por AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, web

Tengo un formulario primario dónde hago una acción de envío por AJAX y de seguido recojo la información en un segundo formulario donde hago una consulta, la cual la segmento en una tabla con  un 
while en php. La información la devuelvo en un responsetext de AJAX para mostarla en el formulario principal.

En la parte de la tabla pongo la información traida de la bd en un . Dentro de esos td tengo buttons con la idea que cuando de clic en el button, me envíe información a un tercer formulario para hacer otra consulta.

Éste es el formulario principal:

```
/* SCRIPT PARA ENVIAR DATOS MEDIANTE AJAX */

$("input[type=button]").click(function(){

    var save = $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "consultar_grupo_sup_chequeo.php",
        data:'category=' + cat + '&fecha=' + fecha,
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        success: function(){
            console.log('Se está ejecutando la solicitud...');
            $("select[name=categoria]").val('');
            $("input[name=fecha]").val('');
        }
    }).responseText;

    document.getElementById('elemetos_dos').innerHTML = save;

      //console.log(save);
});



});
```

Este es el formulario secundario donde recibo los datos y hago la consulta:

```
 <label for="">Aprobadas <?php echo $fecha;?></label>

         <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Supervisor</th>
                  <th scope="col">Aprobadas</th>
              </thead>


        <?php 

        $rawdata = array();

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

                        $rawdata[$i] = $row;
                        $i++;

        ?>
        <input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $row['CC_SUPERVISOR']; ?> id="cc_sup" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td data-label="Nombre"><?php echo $row['NOMBRES'];?></td>
              <!-- TD DONDE SE ANEXA LA CEDULA DEL TECNICO PARA LLEVARLO A UNA VENTANA  Y MIRAR LAS CHECKLIST FIRMADAS POR EL SUPERVISOR -->
              <td data-label="Realizadas"><button id="btn_cc"><?php echo $row['CANTIDAD'];?><button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>


        <?php

        }

        ?>

      </table>
```

En la parte donde están los button he intendado con un script para que cuando le den click sobre el button tome información que hay en la caja de texto hidden:

```
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $row['CC_SUPERVISOR']; ?> id="cc_sup" >
```

pero no lo toma. El script con el que he intentado trabajar es este:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn_cc").mouseup(function(){
            var alertad = $("#cc_sup").val();
            alert(alertad);
        });
```

Comment: Si `#btn_cc` es un elemento que se crea mediante la consulta de AJAX, tenés que usar `$(document).on('mouseup', '#btn_cc', function() {...});`

Comment: Lo probaré, muchas gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Hola, he hecho esto y aún no me funciona:

 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#btn_cc").on('mouseup', function () {
          //var alertad = $("#cc_sup").val();
          console.log("hola");
   });
  });

Otra cosa. El scripti debo hacerlo sobre el formulario principal? 
O sobre formulario secundario?

Comment: copia mi código tal cual, no tenés que usar `$("#btn_cc")...`, tenés que usar `$(document).on("mouseup", "btn_cc"...`

Comment: Hermano, muchas gracias de verdad. Me ha servido,

Comment: Si con eso solucionaste tu problema, ahora lo publico como una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si `#btn_cc` es un elemento que no está inicialmente en el `DOM` (en éste caso lo traes mediante `AJAX`), tenés que usar el [método on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on("mouseup", "#btn_cc", function() {
    var alertad = $("#cc_sup").val();
    alert(alertad);
});
```

El bind se lo asignas a un elemento que ya exista (en este caso `document`), y luego como `selector` pasas el elemento sobre el que querés que funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías vincular los controladores a los eventos de los elementos una vez que éstos se han creado, es decir, después de incluir en el DOM el código HTML recibido por ajax:

```
$("input[type=button]").click(function(){
  var save = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "consultar_grupo_sup_chequeo.php",
      data:'category=' + cat + '&fecha=' + fecha,
      dataType: "html",
      async: false,
      success: function(){
          console.log('Se está ejecutando la solicitud...');
          $("select[name=categoria]").val('');
          $("input[name=fecha]").val('');
      }
    }).responseText;

  document.getElementById('elemetos_dos').innerHTML = save;

  $("#btn_cc").mouseup(function(){
    var alertad = $("#cc_sup").val();
    alert(alertad);
  });
});
```

Por otra parte no deberías utilizar llamadas ajax síncronas. Éstas están deprecadas y no se sabe  durante cuánto tiempo los navegadores seguirán soportándolas. Deberías modificar tu código para utilizar siempre llamadas asíncronas.

Comment: Qué atributo se debería utilizar entonces  hacer llamadas asíncronas?

Comment: Para que la llamada sea asíncrona dentro del objeto en que se definen las opciones de la llamada deberías establecer `async: true` en lugar de `async: false`. Ten en cuenta que deberás cambiar tu código ya que cambiaría el flujo de ejecución de éste. Cualquier código que quieras que se ejecute después de realizar la llamada debería estar en las funciones de callback asociadas a las propiedades `success`, `error` o `complete`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu recomendación. La tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante en mis desarrollos. Éxitos.

Comment: `success` `error` y `complete` son obsoletas. Conviene usar `done` `fail` y `always`.

Comment: Cierto @azeós. Un despiste.